# jquery change text in div

Tags: jquery

Right now the div text is being changed to "text" I need it to be changed to the "data-text" from the link.

```
<a href="1884.html" class="brieflink" data-src="article.jpg" data-text="text4">Brief 4</a>

<div id="brieftext"><p>Text to be replaced</p></div>

$("a.brieflink").bind("mouseover", function() {
    $("div#brieftext").text("text", $(this).data("text"));
});
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? If you're trying to replace text, just say `.html("sometext")` on `div`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
$("div#brieftext").text($(this).attr("data-text"));
```

I have been learned:

```
$("div#brieftext").text($(this).data("text"));
```

will also work after 1.4, thanks @Rocket.

Comment: my bad, I went a little old school there. :)

Answer (score 2):

`.text()` only takes 1 parameter.

```
$("div#brieftext").text($(this).data("text"));
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.text()` takes one argument only. Try:

```
$("div#brieftext").text( $(this).data("text") );
```